# As the window resizes resize everytinhg in tkinter GUI as well

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I've made this simple program. The problem is that I did not think in advance that when the window is resized I want all objects inside it to resize as well. Is there any way to write something simple which would affect everything below instead of writing something to every single line? To make things more clear you can run my code and resize window. You will understand where the problem is:

````
from tkinter import * 
import sys
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import math
import tkinter.font as TkFont

root = tk.Tk()


#Lango dydis
#root.geometry("500x600+0+0")
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 600

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH )
canvas.pack()

frame=Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=5)
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

trikampis = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:/Pytono projektai/240px-Rtriangle.png"))
trikampis2 = Label(root, image=trikampis)
trikampis2.place(relx= 0.29, rely= 0.2)


def skaiciuotuvas():
    error = Label(root, width=1, bg='#80c1ff', fg='#80c1ff')
    error.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.12, rely= 0.905)
    a1 = ae.get()
    b1 = be.get()
    c1 = ce.get()
    if a1 == '':
        b11 = float(b1)
        c11 = float(c1)
        a11 = float(c11)**2 - float(b11)**2
        a12 = math.sqrt(a11)
        a13 = '{:.5}'.format(a12)
        ae.insert(0, a13)
        a111 = '{:.5}'.format(a11)
        saknies.config(text=a111)
        a20 = '{:.10}'.format(a12)
        galutinis.config(text=a20)
        b20 = b11
        c20 = c11
    if b1 == '':
        a11 = float(a1)
        c11 = float(c1)
        b11 = float(c11)**2 - float(a11)**2
        b12 = math.sqrt(b11)
        b13 = '{:.5}'.format(b12)
        be.insert(0, b13)
        b111 = '{:.5}'.format(b11)
        saknies.config(text=b111)
        b20 = '{:.10}'.format(b12)
        galutinis.config(text=b20)
        a20 = a11
        c20 = c11
    if c1 == '':
        a11 = float(a1)
        b11 = float(b1)
        c11 = float(a11)**2 + float(b11)**2
        c12 = math.sqrt(c11)
        c13 = '{:.5}'.format(c12)
        ce.insert(0, c13)
        c111 = '{:.5}'.format(c11)
        saknies.config(text=c111)
        c20 = '{:.10}'.format(c12)
        galutinis.config(text=c20)
        a20 = a11
        b20 = b11
    elif (a1 != '') and (b1 != '') and (c1 != ''):
        error = Label(root, width=1, text='BENT VIENA REIKŠMĖ TURI BŪTI NEŽINOMA!', font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white', fg='red')
        error.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.12, rely= 0.905)
    ploto1 = float(a20)
    ploto2 = float(b20)
    plotass = (ploto1*ploto2)/2
    plotassg = '{:.10}'.format(plotass)
    plotoats.config(text=plotassg)
    perimetro1 = float(a20)
    perimetro2 = float(b20)
    perimetro3 = float(c20)
    perimetrof = perimetro1 + perimetro2 + perimetro3
    perimetroff = '{:.9}'.format(perimetrof)
    perimetroats.config(text=perimetroff)

def resetas():
    error = Label(root, width=1, bg='#80c1ff', fg='#80c1ff')
    error.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.12, rely= 0.905)
    ae.delete(0, END)
    be.delete(0, END)
    ce.delete(0, END)
    saknies.config(text='')
    galutinis.config(text='')
    plotoats.config(text='')
    perimetroats.config(text='')


plotoats = Label(root, width=1, font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white', text='')
plotoats.place(relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.55, rely= 0.85)

plotas = Label(root, width=1, font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white', text='Trikampio plotas = ')
plotas.place(relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.24, rely= 0.85)

plotoats = Label(root, width=1, font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white', text='')
plotoats.place(relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.55, rely= 0.85)



perimetras = Label(root, width=1, font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white', text='Trikampio perimetras = ')
perimetras.place(relwidth=0.37, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.21, rely= 0.795)

perimetroats = Label(root, width=1, font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white', text='')
perimetroats.place(relwidth=0.19, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.59, rely= 0.795)






ats = Label (root, width=1, font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white', text='Ats.: ')
ats.place(relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.21, rely= 0.74)


im = Image.open("E:/Pytono projektai/square-root-symbol-png-3.png")
new_size = im.resize((36, 16))
ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_size)
label = Label(image=ph)
label.place(relx= 0.32, rely= 0.74)

saknies = Label(root, width=1, font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white', text='')
saknies.place(relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.40, rely= 0.74)

lygu = Label(root, width=1, font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white', text='=')
lygu.place(relwidth=0.05, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.515, rely= 0.74)

galutinis = Label(root, width=1, font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white', text='')
galutinis.place(relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.58, rely= 0.74)

skaiciuoti = Button(text='SKAIČIUOTI', font='Verdana 12 bold', command=skaiciuotuvas)
skaiciuoti.place(relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.29, rely= 0.62)

reset = Button(text='RESET', font='Verdana 12 bold', command=resetas)
reset.place(relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.29, rely= 0.68)

a = Label(root, width=1, text='a=', font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white')
a.place(relwidth=0.04, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.18, rely= 0.38)

ae = Entry(root, width=1, font=10, border=2)
ae.place(relwidth=0.09, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.23, rely= 0.38)

b = Label(root, width=1, text='b=', font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white')
b.place(relwidth=0.04, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.38, rely= 0.562)

be = Entry(root, width=1, font=10, border=2)
be.place(relwidth=0.09, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.43, rely= 0.562)

c = Label(root, width=1, text='c=', font='Verdana 12 bold', bg='white')
c.place(relwidth=0.04, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.50, rely= 0.37)

ce = Entry(root, width=1, font=10, border=2,)
ce.place(relwidth=0.09, relheight=0.04, relx= 0.545, rely= 0.37)

root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to solve your problem is to change every `.place` method you use into `.grid` or `.pack`. In my opinion using mentioned methods is way simpler and faster than using [place](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm).

Place method allows you to set relative or absolute position, which in fact you are doing. It is useful when you want to make your widgets change size/position according to it's parent. If it is not your intention you should use [grid](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) or [pack](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)